# I would like to round a variable to the nearest 1 decimal in python & calculate freq

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below data frame:

```
df = [1.2, 0.2, 1.5, 2.49, 2.5, 25.5, 25.49, 14.1, 15.5, 8, 9, 9.6, 5.8, 4.7]
```

I want to calculate the rounded value of df.

For example:

=0.5 <=1.49 should be 1

=1.5 <=2.49 should be 2

```
Expected output = [1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 26, 25, 14, 16, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5]
```

After that how could I calculate the frequency table? In this case the output would be like:

```
Bin = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16, 25, 26]

freq = [1,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
```

But I also want to fill the gap between the bin values.

For example there is no freq. available for 4,7,11,12,13,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 then it should become 0.

And the final output should be:

```
Bin = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]

freq = [1,  1,  2,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math 

df = [1.2, 0.2, 1.5, 2.49, 2.5, 25.5, 25.49, 14.1, 15.5, 8, 9, 9.6, 5.8, 4.7]

df = [math.floor(x) if x%1 < .5 else math.ceil(x) for x in df]

freq = {x:0 for x in range(0, max(df)+1)}
for x in df:
    freq[x] += 1

print(freq)
```

Which gives this output:

{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 1, 15: 0, 16: 1, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 1, 26: 1}

If it absolutely has to be in lists then

```
bins = []
counts = []
for k, v in freq.items():
    bins.append(k)
    counts.append(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it is correct please. Thanks